# creating a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below code:

```
list_one = ['a', 'b']
list_two = ['1', '2']
list_three = {}
```

what I want to end up with is:

```
list_three = {
        'a':{1:[], 2:[]},
        'b':{1:[], 2:[]}
    }
```

I'm trying some crazy FOR x IN y loops but not getting the reuslt I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use nested-dictionary-comprehension:

```
print({k:{int(k2):[] for k2 in list_two} for k in list_one})
```

Output:

```
{'a': {1: [], 2: []}, 'b': {1: [], 2: []}}
```

Comment: Careful: `d['a']['1'].append("hello")` probably doesn't do you what you want.

Comment: That's the ticket! learned something new too, will mark as answer after timer

Comment: @AriVictor Happy to help!, :-).

Comment: @MarkMeyer Now?

Comment: Slight difference in output of this vs OP's expected output, OP wants integer keys.

Comment: Yeah @U9-Forward, no more shared reference.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Ahh I see what you mean now, if I am trying to do d['a']['1'].append("hello") how would I go about it

Comment: @Tomothy32 I won't edit, because then it will be to confusing, also, OP should knw how tio do that.

Comment: @AriVictor I already edited mine, it's the bottom of my post.

Comment: `.from_keys` is straight wrong here. DV until removed... (Second part is fine...)

Comment: `.from_keys` only uses a static reference, so `[]` is the same list.  Just use the nested dict comprehension (where `[]` is called for each sub key) and you are good to go.

Comment: @dawg hahahahaha, :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could always make a nested [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

list_one = ['a', 'b']
list_two = ['1', '2']

d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))

for x in list_one:
    for y in list_two:
        d[x][int(y)]

pprint(d)
```

Which will automatically initialize a list inside for you:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000002AEA8D4C1E0>,
            {'a': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [], 2: []}),
             'b': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [], 2: []})})
```

You can then append values to these inner lists, since `defaultdict()` initialised empty lists for you.

Addtionally, you can also use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) here aswell:

```
list_one = ['a', 'b']
list_two = ['1', '2']

d = {}
for x in list_one:
    d.setdefault(x, {})
    for y in list_two:
        d[x].setdefault(int(y), [])

print(d)
# {'a': {1: [], 2: []}, 'b': {1: [], 2: []}}
```